# Is there any use for declaring a variable as read-only with no value?

Tags: bash

This bash statement `declare -r myvar` declares `myvar` as read-only with no value set. 
Is there any use for declaring a variable as read-only with no value?

Comment: With no value set *by the `declare` operation*. If a value was provided earlier, it will remain.

Answer (score 2):

First, if the variable is initially unset, this prevents it from having a value (even an empty value!) set later, thus (in current bash 4.x -- as contrasted to older versions where such a read-only variable is considered to have the empty-string value assigned) establishing that unset status as invariant for the life of the shell instance.

Second, there's reason to use this with a value that *isn't* initially unset: Using `declare` to set flags for a variable modifies `$?`. That isn't always desirable. Consider:

```
declare -r result="$(my-command)" || exit
```

Even if `my-command` fails, the exit status of that command is `0`, because `declare` succeeds, so `exit` is never run. By contrast:

```
result=$(my-command) || exit
declare -r result
```

...properly exits if `my-command` fails.